# How to add an attribute to an existing node using Xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an xml as below.

```
<test>
<a att1="1">
</test>
```

How to add an new attribute to the existing node  ? Expected output is as follows.

```
<test>
<a att1="1" att2="2">
</test>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this function.

```
  functx:add-attributes(
  $in-xml/a,
  (xdmp:node-insert-after('att1','att2')) or (xdmp:node-insert-before('att1','att2')),(1,2)).
```

Comment: Any other way instead of using functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Using XQuery Update and BaseX, following will be the solution -

```
for $x in doc('Document2')//a
return 
insert node attribute att2{'2'} into $x
```

I hope you already have the answer, still...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with the below Xquery in MarkLogic.

```
(: create a document :)
xdmp:document-insert("/example.xml", <a/>);

(: insert an attribute as child of a :)    
xdmp:node-insert-child(doc("/example.xml")/a,
attribute b { "bbb" });

(: look at the new document :)
fn:doc("/example.xml")

**Output**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a b="bbb"/>
```

Source : [xdmp:node-insert-child](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-insert-child)